# Obtain NetworkCredentils or ClientCredentials in WebAPI controller with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, windows-authentication

I have a WebAPI application with Windows Authentication. I need to create connection with external application (MS Dynamics CRM 2016) inside WebAPI controller, but I cannot obtain password of connected to WebAPI user.

Is there any possibility to obtain `NetworkCredentials` or `ClientCredentials` object in WebAPI controller? I can get username and domain of connected user, but not password. `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` object is empty.

```
public class ParametersController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetParameters()
    {
        NetworkCredential defaultNetworkCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //null

        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get the password from windows authentication for the same reason that you cannot make a public website with windows authentication where you can get all the password of the visitors account without them knowing. This is a security feature.